# Narrowing down loop to only print if certain conditions are satisfied

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have the following code

```
Table[Riffle[Mod[{i, DivisorSigma[1, 7 i + 4]}, 47], Sqrt[7 i + 4]], {i, 200}]
```

and it works perfectly fine. There are two modifications which I would like help with:

1. How can I print the index `i` without it being `Mod[47]`?
2. This part is more complicated. I am trying to narrow down the loop to only print if the following conditions are satisfied: a) The number is actually a perfect square & b) The number `7 i + 4` is congruent to `0 mod 47`. So unless those two conditions are satisfied I do not want it to print.

Comment: What do you mean by `print`?

Comment: I guess I mean that I do not need a table necesarilly, I just want to know when it satisfies conditions a & b . If it does not satisfy them then I do not need to see any output

Comment: Use `Select` to only keep the items you want. Like this: `Select[Table[yourstuff],IntegerQ[Sqrt[#[[2]]]]&]` which will only keep the items where the square root of the second item in each pair is an integer. Then you can think how to add another condition to  also limit it to satisfy your condition a.

Comment: For the first part, do you mean `Table[{i, Sqrt[7 i + 4], Mod[DivisorSigma[1, 7 i + 4], 47]}, {i, 200}]`?

Comment: Have you looked at [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)? I think they work well for applying your constraints.

Comment: m_goldberg no i have not, i will check it out thank you

Comment: I think there are not many numbers $i$ that are perfect squares and at the same time satisfy $7i+4=0$ mod 47. Check: `Select[Range[10^6]^2, Mod[7 # + 4, 47] == 0 &]` returns nothing.

Comment: @Roman Using `Divisible[7 # + 4]&` may be marginally faster than calculating the `Mod` and checking if it is zero. For instance `Select[Range[10^7]^2, Divisible[7 # + 4, 47] &]` still returns nothing, but it takes roughly 4 seconds less than the `Mod` version.

Comment: @MarcoB surprisingly, `Select[Range[10^7]^2, Mod[7 #, 47] == 43 &]` is even faster.

Comment: @Roman Interesting! It is not obvious to me why that would be the case.

Comment: Still much faster: `FreeQ[Mod[7*Range[10^7]^2, 47], 43]` takes only 0.5 seconds, and `Lookup[Counts[Mod[7*Range[10^7]^2, 47]], 43, 0]` only 0.2 seconds. Surprising that the latter is faster than the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like the following:

```
Select[
 Array[{#, #^2} &, 10000000],
 Divisible[7 Last[#] + 4, 47] &
]
```

This generates the first $10^7$ perfect squares, associated with the corresponding integer $i$ of which they are a square, then tests whether the expression $7\ i^2+4$ is divisible by 47.

The problem is, there are no such numbers up to $i=10^7$...